# Unable to initilize webpack template using vue cli

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-loader

I try to initialize webpack using vue cli based on below guide provided.

https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/

But, When i run below command i facing error.

```
$ npm install -g vue-cli
```

Error Message

> vue-cli · Failed to download repo vuejs-templates/webpack: write
> EPROTO 8C6A0000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe
> legacy renegotiation
> disabled:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\extensions.c:922: